# how to count common values ina array

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array (
        [attendance_id] => 18 
        [attendance] => 1
        [student_id] => 1
        [date] => 2015-01-19
        [in_time] => 00:00:00 
        [out_time] => 00:00:00
        [fee_amount] => 15000 ) 
Array (
        [attendance_id] => 19 
        [attendance] => 1 
        [student_id] => 2
        [date] => 2015-01-19
        [in_time] => 00:00:00
        [out_time] => 00:00:00 
        [fee_amount] => 2000 ) 
Array (
        [attendance_id] => 20 
        [attendance] => 0
        [student_id] => 1
        [date] => 2014-01-15 
        [in_time] => 00:00:00 
        [out_time] => 00:00:00 
        [fee_amount] => 0 
      )
```

I want to count the common values in these Arrays. Please guide how to do this.

As result I want to get this:

```
 date      [2014-01-15 ] => 2
 attendance [1]  => 2
```

This is actually for a small institute where single student details for a day may entered into the system as above. So I just want to make a report day end saying how many students has come to the class on specific day and how many didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
   <?php
$array = array(array('18','2015-01-19','15000'),array('2015-01-19','18','22'),array('20','11','22'));

$newcountarray = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
foreach ($value as $newvalue) {
    if ($foundKey = array_key_exists($newvalue,$newcountarray)) {
        $newcountarray[$newvalue] += 1;
    }
   else{
      $newcountarray[$newvalue] = 1;
   }
}}

print_r($newcountarray);

?>
```

**Output**

```
 Array ( [18] => 2 [2015-01-19] => 2 [15000] => 1 [22] => 2 [20] => 1 [11] => 1 )
```

Comment: i guess this may not work as both attendance and student_id all having 1 as value in the array. plus this is array of arrays

Comment: @user3696108 i have update my answer.check it and let me know

Comment: @onegun i have update my answer.check it and let me know

Comment: thanks bro it worked for certain limit, result is ok .is there any way to figure that for the day [2015-01-19] hw many [1] =>? ? and [2]=> ??

Comment: u want create array like that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Deena Let's say

```
$array = array(array('18',<==row id no 
       '2015-01-19',<=date
       '1',<=student id>   
       '2'<=present(1),absent(2))),

       array(array('19',<==row id no 
       '2015-01-19',<=date
       '2',<=student id>   
       '1'<=present(1),absent(2))),
```

its like for the day 2015-01-19 i want to get all 2 stuudent and among them 1 Student is present and 1 is absent